# SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';' declaring object

Tags: javascript

Error reported in Firefox Developers Edition, version 59.0b7 (64-bit)

The script in question

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: ['23053727'],
ecomm_pagetype: 'cart',
ecomm_totalvalue: 103.48
}; // <---<<< ERROR LINE

</script>
```

Looks legit to me

? has the Firefox got confused with ES rrow syntax ?

Comment: Why do you put `;` between `**` ?

Comment: Does `**;**` seem legit to you? Why?

Comment: High lit semicolon - clicked bold button - hey presto - markup inconsistant

Comment: Just to cover all bases-  you're sure there's no hidden characters hanging around? Does it work in Chrome etc?

Comment: I dont see any error on my console,